# Is a continuous interval countable or uncountable infinite?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I wondered if a continuous interval like $[0,1]^{\mathbb{R}}$ has countable or uncountable infinite elements.

So i looked for a bijective mapping and found following:

$f:\mathbb{N} \to ]0,1[^{\mathbb{R}}$

$f:x \mapsto \frac{x}{10^{\lfloor\log_{10}x\rfloor+1}}$

$f(1234) = 0.1234$

Therefore $[0,1]^{\mathbb{R}}$ should have countable infinite elements, shouldn't it?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! What exactly do you denote $[0,1]^{\mathbb R}$?

Comment: You have generated countably many elements of $[0,1]^\mathbb{R}$, but it doesn't mean the set $[0,1]^\mathbb{R}$ is countable. The only thing we can conclude from your argument is the set $[0,1]^\mathbb{R}$ is infinite.

Comment: Could you please share with us fo what $\alpha\in\Bbb N$ does $f(\alpha)$ equal $\frac13$?

Comment: I'm way too lazy to find you all the uncountably many duplicates that this question has on this website. But I encourage you to set out on a quest to try and do so yourself. Also, you keep using the notation $A^\Bbb R$, I do not think it means what you think it means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is not surjective. For example, it won't hit $\frac{1}{\sqrt2} \in [0,1]$, since that's an irrational number.